# Trying to compare two strings in python

Tags: python

I even used print statements to check if y.name and favourite were the same when checking this and they were yet it still wasn't entering the if statement when using

```
if y.name == favourite
```

or

```
if favourite ==y.name
```

I'm super confused as to why that is since I thought this was just a standard equality check (The beginning of the code is mostly set up, just included it for context in the case that there was a problem there and not the if statement). Thank you in advance!

```
class Anime(object):
    name: str = ""
    year_aired = 0
    genre1: str = ""

    def __init__(self, name, genre1, year_aired):
        self.name = name
        self.genre1 = genre1
        self.year_aired = year_aired


def _make_anime(name, genre1, year_aired):
    anime = Anime()
    return anime


animelist = input("Please enter a file with a list of anime\n")
animel = open(animelist, "r")
nolines = animel.readlines()
animearr = []
numanime = -1
for i in nolines:
    if i.find("*") != -1:
        animearr[numanime].genre1 = i
    else:
        k = Anime("","", 2018)
        k.name = i
        animearr.append(k)
        numanime += 1
favourite = input("Please enter your favourite anime\n")
favgenre = ""
for y in animearr:
    if y.name == favourite:
        favgenre = y.genre1
print(favgenre)
```

Comment: They must be unequal in a way that's hard to see visually -- maybe one has a space at the end or something.  Try printing `repr(favourite)` and `repr(y.name)`.

Comment: Also indent / format your code correctly and give [mcve] please.

Comment: It would help us greatly if you properly indent your code. Would you please? 4 spaces per indentation level would be the norm.

Comment: Lines read from a file will have a newline character at the end of the line. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). You probably need to [**`strip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) it off.

Comment: Sorry for the indentation issues I'm completely new to python and this is the first question I have ever asked myself on stack overflow... I think it is a "strip" issue.... In my program it is indented correctly, I was confused on how to post on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add strip.("\n") before you compare two string.

```
class Anime(object):
    name: str = ""
    year_aired = 0
    genre1: str = ""

    def __init__(self, name, genre1, year_aired):
        self.name = name
        self.genre1 = genre1
        self.year_aired = year_aired


def _make_anime(name, genre1, year_aired):
    anime = Anime()
    return anime


animelist = input("Please enter a file with a list of anime\n")
animel = open(animelist, "r")
nolines = animel.readlines()
animearr = []
numanime = -1
for i in nolines:
    if i.find("*") != -1:
        animearr[numanime].genre1 = i
    else:
        k = Anime("","", 2018)
        k.name = i
        animearr.append(k)
        numanime += 1
favourite = input("Please enter your favourite anime\n")
favgenre = ""
for y in animearr:
    if y.name == favourite.strip("\n"):

        favgenre = y.genre1
print(favgenre)
```